# How do I set default text for description field on the enter bug page? Description will need to change on update of one of the custom fields

Tags: javascript, bugzilla

I have done this using javascript for the edit bug page, where I used a change of the bug status to modify the default text. This was done by calling a javascript function onchange of the bug status. 
I am now trying to do a similar operation on the enter bug page, but I need the default text to change based on the issue type. As this is a custom field it does not show up in the template files, so I cant (that I am aware of) use the onchange in the select tag for the issue type drop down menu. Is there another way of using the onchange feature to call a javascript function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I have accomplished something similar is to modify `field.html.tmpl` which is where the HTML for the custom fields is rendered.  You would find the place in the code where it is rendering your field (e.g. `[% CASE [constants.FIELD_TYPE_SINGLE_SELECT`).  Then you could add in your own code to include an onchange handler as appropriate for your particular situation.

Something like this (note: Bugzilla 3.2.3):

```
[% CASE [ constants.FIELD_TYPE_SINGLE_SELECT 
          constants.FIELD_TYPE_MULTI_SELECT ] %]
    <select id="[% field.name FILTER html %]" 
            name="[% field.name FILTER html %]" 
            [% IF field.type == constants.FIELD_TYPE_MULTI_SELECT %]
                [% SET field_size = 5 %]
                [% IF field.legal_values.size < 5 %]
                    [% SET field_size = field.legal_values.size %]
                [% END %]
                size="[% field_size FILTER html %]" multiple="multiple"
            [% END %]

            [%# BEGIN ADDED CODE %]
            [% IF field.name == 'cf_mycustomissuetypefield' %]
                onchange="javascript:updateDescription()"
            [% END %]
            [%# END ADDED CODE %]
            >
```

Comment: Thats worked thanks, I had just been looking in the wrong places for the select tag.